# Apache “<VirtualHost> was not closed” error - despite it clearly being closed

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I am having a really annoying issue where my newly created Apache Vhost is causing config error. I initially use cp command to copy existing and working vhost and just changed the DocumentRoot. Apache would fail to reload and restart.

Running apache2 -t results in error below:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 220 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.example.com.conf: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.example.com.conf:1: <VirtualHost> was not closed.
```

Here is my vhost stripped to the bare bones (I am running this exact code):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin example@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test

        ServerName      ddns.example.com
        ServerAlias     www.test.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If I disable this vhost Apache starts fine and no config errors are shows from apache2 -t command. I've gone and manually retyped the vhost opening/closing tags and checked for empty space. test directory does exist and has www-root:www-root ownership. What is causing this seemingly false error?

Answer (score 1):

Included Apache configuration files like the virtual host configuration files are read in order. Despite the error points to this file and the line number 1 where it actualizes, the problem is **a missing `</VirtualHost>` at the end of the previous file**. That's the previous file in an alphabetical order. It's not an error until there's an unexpected `<VirtualHost>` statement.

Comment: I have now checked all sites-enabled vhosts and they all have closing tags. This is the only vhost causing issues and its in the middle alphabetically. Also wouldn't apache -t show an error if tags not closed? I bet it's something particularly simple but I cannot see it...

Comment: Also if I add </VirtualHost> at the top of the troublesome vhost file I get and error:  "apache2: Syntax error on line 220 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.example.com.conf: </VirtualHost> without matching <VirtualHost> section"